# How to avoid the pitfall of implicit conversion to int that makes 7/8*pi = 0

Tags: int, implicit-conversion

Too many times, I am coding things like double t = 7/8*pi, only to find out, that t equals 0 after that. Why? Because of an implicit conversion to int. The right result can be obtained by rearranging the numbers double t = 7*pi/8. Now the nominater is a double and no conversion happens. (or double t = 7d/8*pi or 7f or 7.0 or ...)

The problem is, it is so intuitiv to make it wrong!

How can I prevent it? Does it make sense to turn of implicit conversion to int completely and how would I do it?

Comment: Indeed sensible languages often offer a separate operator for integer division. (Pascal, Algol68 DIV, also seen `÷`). More a hint for a language developer.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a matter of precedence?  What I do is use 7.0 and or 8.0 since I know I want to avoid integer arithmetic. Once you get used to it, it seems natural.

Answer (score 0):

In Java [**FindBugs**](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) may warn about such constructs.

> ICAST: Integral division result cast to double or float
>   (ICAST_IDIV_CAST_TO_DOUBLE)
>
> This code casts the result of an integral division (e.g., int or long
>   division) operation to double or float. Doing division on integers
>   truncates the result to the integer value closest to zero. The fact
>   that the result was cast to double suggests that this precision should
>   have been retained. What was probably meant was to cast one or both of
>   the operands to double before performing the division. Here is an
>   example:
>
> ```
> int x = 2;
> int y = 5;
> // Wrong: yields result 0.0
> double value1 =  x / y;
>
> // Right: yields result 0.4
> double value2 =  x / (double) y;
> ```